# Replace nth element of a string with the element in another column

Tags: string, postgresql, replaceall

How do I replace a string element with another column value in PostgreSQL?

For example:
My table has two columns:

```
element  seq
T       AAACGGG
G       TTTATTT
```

I want to replace the fourth element with the element mentioned in first column.

Expected output:

```
element  seq     new_seq
T       AAACGGG  AAATGGG
G       TTTATTT  TTTGTTT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a regex based solution, then use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    element,
    seq,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(seq, '^(.{3}).(.*)', '\1' || element || '\2') AS new_seq
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

We could also just use `SUBSTRING` here for a base string option:

```
SELECT
    element,
    seq,
    SUBSTRING(seq, 1, 3) || element || SUBSTRING(seq, 5) AS new_seq
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The substring approach might outperform the regex approach, so this might be what to use if you are really concerned with performance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overlay function that you can use.

```sql
SELECT
  element,
  seq,
  overlay(seq placing element from 4 for 1) new_seq
FROM rna;
```

The first number argument is the start character and the second is for how many characters you change.